# Curved buttons and a circle

Tags: android, button

Hey I was wondering if there is any way to do this without going insane with lil buttons built up to make it but basically what I want to do is make two curved buttons around a circle one, is there any way of doing this?

Hers an example of what I kinda want, sorry for how crude the drawing is.

[image: Curved buttons]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two parts in answering this question : how to have buttons looking like this, and getting the touch on the areas you draw.

For the first part, you can use a FrameLayout or a Relative Layout to draw your buttons exactly where you want, and custom images as background (maybe for the circle you can make a ShapeDrawable).

For the second part, it can be very simple : if the Circle (biggest button) is on top of the other two, then this can be ok. But I guess the touchable area on each button will be a rectangle.

Another way to do this is create a custom view, handle the Touch events yourself and based on the X and Y, detect which part has been touched

Comment: The middle button will have to be some type of track pad if thats the right term, I want to receive like positional touch events for it to. Any example code would be really helpful \

Comment: I don't think I understand what you mean by track pad ? Do you want to simulate a track ball with the circle button? You can achieve that using the ACTION_MOVE events.

Comment: I have implemented custom views several times to get the level of control you require, I'd definitely say it's the way to go here.